# Why is my http.put not working in Angular?

Tags: angular, http-post, dx-data-grid

I am making use of a dx-gata-grid to update a db. I have a post and delete that are working as expected but when I try to update an existing row using an http.post it does not work. The grid successfully updates but when refreshed the row hasn't actually updated.

Datagrid OnRowUpdate

```
  onRowUpdating(e) {
    const gridData = e;

    const row = {
      name: gridData.newData.name || gridData.oldData.name,
      expression: gridData.newData.expression || gridData.oldData.expression,
      longterm: gridData.newData.longterm || gridData.oldData.longterm,
      persisted: gridData.newData.persisted || gridData.oldData.persisted,
      status: gridData.newData.status || gridData.oldData.status
    };

    this.RowManagerService.updateRow(gridData.oldData.id, row)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((data: any) => {
        this.toastMessageService.showSuccess(' Successfully Updated Row');
      }, (error) => {
        this.toastMessageService.showFailure(' Something went wrong when updating the Row.');
      });
  }
```

updateRow method

```
updateRow(rowID, data): Observable<any> {
    const endPoint = this.formatString(this.url + '/update/${id}', {
      id: rowID,
    });

    return this.http.put<any>(this.requestUrl + endPoint, data, {headers: this.headers})
      .pipe(map((response: any) => {
          return response;
        }),
        catchError(this.error));
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

As far as i can see you are subscribing to the response but you  are not doing anything with in. You only show a toastmessage.

```
this.RowManagerService.updateRow(gridData.oldData.id, row)
      .pipe(takeUntil(this.unsubscribe))
      .subscribe((data: any) => { // YOU NEED TO DO SOMETHING WITH THIS DATA!
        this.toastMessageService.showSuccess(' Successfully Updated Row');
       RETURN DATA;
      }, (error) => {
        this.toastMessageService.showFailure(' Something went wrong when updating the Row.');
      });
```

Comment: I don't understand? That is what my updateRow function is for.